# Atualizar cadastro de formulário com foto Laravel

Tags: laravel, formulário

É o seguinte,
Tenho um sistema de cadastro em laravel, na parte de editar, o formulário carrega os campos preenchidos com a foto, se eu clicar em atualizar e não escolher um arquivo de imagem novamente aparece o erro: "**Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null**".

CONTROLLER

```
public function  detalhes($id, Request $request){
    $data = array();
    $data["lista"] = \App\Curso::all();
    try{
        $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);
        if($request->isMethod("POST")){

            $matricula = $request->input("matricula", "");
            $nome = $request->input("nome", "");
            $telefone = $request->input("telefone", "");
            $sexo = $request->input("sexo", "");
            $email = $request->input("email", "");
            $endereco = $request->input("endereco", "");
            $bairro = $request->input("bairro", "");
            $cep = $request->input("cep", "");
            $cidade = $request->input("cidade", "");
            $estado = $request->input("estado", "");
            $idcurso = $request->input("idcurso", "");

            $file = $request->file("foto");
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $size = $file->getSize();

            if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"){
                $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                        . "Escolha uma IMAGEM valida</div>";
                //2MB
            }else if($size > (1024 * 1024 * 2)){
                $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                        . "Tamanho da imagem invalido</div>";
            }else{

            $fileName = "ft_" .date('YmdHis').".".$ext;

            $alu->matricula = $matricula;
            $alu->nome = $nome;
            $alu->telefone = $telefone;
            $alu->sexo = $sexo;
            $alu->email = $email;
            $alu->idcurso = $idcurso;
            $alu->foto = $fileName;

            $alu->save();

            $idend = $alu->endereco->idendereco;

            $e = \App\Endereco::find($idend);

            $e->endereco = $endereco;
            $e->bairro = $bairro;
            $e->cidade = $cidade;
            $e->cep = $cep;
            $e->estado = $estado;

            $e->aluno()->associate($alu);

            $e->save();

            $file->move("fotos", $fileName);

            $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>"
                    . "Aluno editado com sucesso!</div>";

            $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);

            return redirect('admin/buscar.html');
        }


        }
         $data["a"] = $alu;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"
                . "Operação não realizada</div>";
    }
    return view('aluno/detalhes', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o Laravel tenta recuperar um arquivo enviado e não consegue, ele retorna `NULL`. Por tanto, antes de verificar a extensão, tamanho ou qualquer outra informação, é necessário utilizar uma condição para verificar se a informação é, ou não, válida.

Você pode fazer a verificação dessa forma:

```
<?php

public function  detalhes($id, Request $request){
    $data = array();
    $data["lista"] = \App\Curso::all();

    try{
        $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);

        if($request->isMethod("POST")){

            $matricula = $request->input("matricula", "");
            $nome = $request->input("nome", "");
            $telefone = $request->input("telefone", "");
            $sexo = $request->input("sexo", "");
            $email = $request->input("email", "");
            $endereco = $request->input("endereco", "");
            $bairro = $request->input("bairro", "");
            $cep = $request->input("cep", "");
            $cidade = $request->input("cidade", "");
            $estado = $request->input("estado", "");
            $idcurso = $request->input("idcurso", "");

            $file = $request->file("foto");

            /* Caso o usuário não tenha enviado uma nova foto, ignora o trecho abaixo */
            if ($file != null) {
                $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $size = $file->getSize();

                if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"){
                    $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                            . "Escolha uma IMAGEM valida</div>";
                    //2MB
                }else if($size > (1024 * 1024 * 2)){
                    $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                            . "Tamanho da imagem invalido</div>";
                }

                $fileName = "ft_" .date('YmdHis').".".$ext;

                $alu->foto = $fileName;
            }


            $alu->matricula = $matricula;
            $alu->nome = $nome;
            $alu->telefone = $telefone;
            $alu->sexo = $sexo;
            $alu->email = $email;
            $alu->idcurso = $idcurso;

            $alu->save();

            $idend = $alu->endereco->idendereco;

            $e = \App\Endereco::find($idend);

            $e->endereco = $endereco;
            $e->bairro = $bairro;
            $e->cidade = $cidade;
            $e->cep = $cep;
            $e->estado = $estado;

            $e->aluno()->associate($alu);

            $e->save();

            // Caso o usuário não tenha enviado uma foto, ignora o trecho abaixo.
            if ($file != null) {
                $file->move("fotos", $fileName);
            }

            $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>"
                    . "Aluno editado com sucesso!</div>";

            $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);

            return redirect('admin/buscar.html');

        }

        $data["a"] = $alu;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"
                . "Operação não realizada</div>";
    }

    return view('aluno/detalhes', $data);
}
```

Comment: Mas ele já carrega a imagem que foi cadastrada, mas se clicar em atualizar dá esse erro como se não estivesse escolhido a imagem ainda. Por exemplo, quero alterar e atualizar só o cep do formulário e manter o restante inclusive a foto que foi carregada. Ele carrega a foto mas é como se não tivesse carregado. Mesmo a foto aparecendo eu tenho que escolher a mesma foto novamente aí ele envia normal.

Comment: @vando entendi. Alterei o código de exemplo. Dessa vez o algoritmo vai verificar se o usuário enviou uma foto, caso tenha enviado, faz a verificação do tamanho e extensão; caso contrário, ignora essa parte.

Comment: Muito obrigado Valdeir, salvou o meu dia.